# kurento: How record webcam to both webm and mp4 recordendpoint?

Tags: webrtc, webcam-capture, kurento

i modified kurento's one2many tutorial (https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/blob/master/kurento-one2many-call/src/main/java/org/kurento/tutorial/one2manycall/CallHandler.java) examples to record the webcam stream to a mp4 or webm file like in below.

Here i commented out the RecorderEndpoint writing the mp4.

My question is, how can i write both files (webm and mp4) from just one WebRtcEndpoint?
I thought about using DispatcherOneToMany (http://www.kurento.org/docs/4.2.0/kmf-media-api/com/kurento/kmf/media/DispatcherOneToMany.html) but setSource needs a HubPort which i didn't get to work with my WebRtcEndpoint masterWebRtc.
So how can i dispatch the masterWebRtc to two RecorderEndpoint's?

Thanks for any help.

```
private synchronized void master(WebSocketSession session,
        JsonObject jsonMessage) throws IOException {
    if (masterUserSession == null) {
        masterUserSession = new UserSession(session);

        pipeline = kurento.createMediaPipeline();
        masterUserSession.setWebRtcEndpoint(new WebRtcEndpoint.Builder(
                pipeline).build());

        WebRtcEndpoint masterWebRtc = masterUserSession.getWebRtcEndpoint();
        String sdpOffer = jsonMessage.getAsJsonPrimitive("sdpOffer")
                .getAsString();
        String sdpAnswer = masterWebRtc.processOffer(sdpOffer);

        JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
        response.addProperty("id", "masterResponse");
        response.addProperty("response", "accepted");
        response.addProperty("sdpAnswer", sdpAnswer);
        masterUserSession.sendMessage(response);

        //RecorderEndpoint recorderEndpoint =  new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(pipeline,"file:///tmp/recording.mp4").withMediaProfile(MediaProfileSpecType.MP4).build();
       RecorderEndpoint recorderEndpoint =  new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(pipeline,"file:///tmp/recording.webm").withMediaProfile(MediaProfileSpecType.WEBM).build();
        masterWebRtc.connect(recorderEndpoint);
        recorderEndpoint.record();

    } else {
        JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
        response.addProperty("id", "masterResponse");
        response.addProperty("response", "rejected");
        response.addProperty("message",
                "Another user is currently acting as sender. Try again later ...");
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(response.toString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kurento, all media elements are "one-to-many" meaning that you can connect a source media element to as many sink media elements as you want. Following you code:

```
RecorderEndpoint recorderEndpointA =  new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(pipeline,"file:///tmp/recording.mp4").withMediaProfile(MediaProfileSpecType.MP4).build();
RecorderEndpoint recorderEndpointB =  new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(pipeline,"file:///tmp/recording.webm").withMediaProfile(MediaProfileSpecType.WEBM).build();

masterWebRtc.connect(recorderEndpointA); //masterWebRtc is source, recorderEndpointA is sink
masterWebRtc.connect(recorderEndpointB); //masterWebRtc is source, recorderEndpointB is sink

//you could connect masterWebRtc to other additional elements here if you want.

recorderEndpointA.record();
recorderEndpointB.record();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working now. One of my problems was that i added .withMediaProfile(MediaProfileSpecType.MP4) later in my tests. This means if you don't use MediaProfileSpecType, by default, kurento saves webm content altough the file's extension was mp4 - don't know why i thought the encoding depends on file extension. my bad.